# Как включить загрузку с NVME на MSI Z77A-G43?

Tags: bios, msi, материнская-плата, nvme

Материнская плата  MSI Z77A-G43  не поддерживает загрузку с NVME. Есть ли какая-то возможность ее включить

Answer (score 0):

Есть модифицированная версия BIOS для поддержки nvme  https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5tcG/62tgP3tv9 (образ модифицированный, так что вы используете его на свой страх и риск), также можно использовать драйвер от  Clover  https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4pBg/LGgpYKbXJ и загрузить его через UEFI-shell